# T-SQL - receive date value and adjust day / month retaining year

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to perform a little date manipulation on a value I will be passing in to a stored procedure.

Example Inputs;

```
31/12/2008 
15/11/2007 
21/05/2005
```

Expected Output;

```
31/12/2012
15/11/2012
21/05/2012
```

Formatted code from the answer provided;

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '31/12/2007'
DECLARE @year INT 
SET @year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @year - DATEPART(YEAR, @date), @date)
```

Comment: What happens on a leap day? Does it roll forward or roll back?

Comment: If running in 2013, and provided with `20120229`, what is the expected output?

Comment: @JohnMitchell 2012 is a leap year so no problem ;-)

Comment: @JohnMitchell That's a very good point however I have some additional code that adjust the date, if it's 28 or above, I set it to the first day of the following month. Well spotted though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert the year component to 2012?

```
-- get the year part
DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])

-- get the number of years to add
2012 - DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])

-- add that many years to the date
DATEADD(YEAR, 2012 - DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]), [Date])
```